# NetSuite Address Field Auto Create

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am trying to write a afterSubmit entry point that auto fills the the sublist and subrecords of the address field on the new Leads form. I can alter a current address using record.load but if no address currently exists(which is always the case with a new lead) and I'm trying to run record.create, nothing happens.

/**

- @NApiVersion 2.x
- @NScriptType UserEventScript
  */

  define([ 'N/record' ],function(record){
  function afterSubmit(context){

  ```
   // Create the record.
   var rec = record.create({
       type: record.Type.LEAD,
       isDynamic: true
   });



   // Create a line in the Address sublist.
   rec.selectNewLine({
       sublistId: 'addressbook'
   });

   // Set an optional field on the sublist line.
   rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
       sublistId: 'addressbook',
       fieldId: 'label',
       value: 'Primary Address'
   });

   // Create an address subrecord for the line.
   var subrec = rec.getCurrentSublistSubrecord({
       sublistId: 'addressbook',
       fieldId: 'addressbookaddress'
   });

   // Set body fields on the subrecord. Because the script uses 
   // dynamic mode, you should set the country value first. The country 
   // value determines which address form is to be used, so by setting
   // this value first, you ensure that the values for the rest 
   // of the form's fields will be set properly.
   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'country',
       value: 'US'
   });

   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'city',
       value: 'San Mateo'
   });

   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'state',
       value: 'CA'
   });

   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'zip',
       value: '94403'
   });

   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'addr1',
       value: '2955 Campus Drive'
   });

   subrec.setValue({
       fieldId: 'addr2',
       value: 'Suite 100'
   });

   // Save the sublist line.
   rec.commitLine({
       sublistId: 'addressbook'
   });

   // Save the record.
   try{
       var recId = rec.save();

       log.debug({
           title: 'Record created successfully',
           details: 'Id: ' + recId
       });
   } catch (e){
       log.error({
           title: e.name,
           details: e.message
       });
   }
  ```

  }
  return {
  afterSubmit: afterSubmit
  };
  });

Comment: Why are you creating a new record here?  The normal way to do what I think you're trying to do would be to edit the record passed in the context argument (`var rec = context.newRecord`).  What you're doing here appears to be creating a new record with *only* an address (IE: no name or any other fields filled) and attempting to save that.